# Weird rotation problem

Tags: animation

[image]

I block poses in constant interpolation, but when I set it to beizer interpolation, it shows weird rotation. Maybe it is bad rig.
[image]
[image]

Comment: could you please share your file? (share the armature only): https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Here's the link for blend file [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=EbY4q0Lb" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/EbY4q0Lb/)

Comment: _Love_ the walk :)

Comment: Thank you @Robin Betts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as switching to *Quaternion* would remove the animation, I guess the easiest way is to create additional keyframes so that Blender knows better how to interpolate.

For example it begins to mess up at frame 9:

[image]

So move and rotate the bone correctly and create a keyframe (<kbd>i</kbd>):

[image]

Keep on doing it at frame 10 and 11, then you can come back and see if you can delete some.

Comment: But I don't know how to switch to quaternion. Can you please tell me

Comment: select the buggy bone, open the right panel (press N), click on the dropdown menu I show and choose Quaternion, do it for each bone for which you see a problem, if it doesn't fix the problem, create intermediate keyframes

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. But what do you mean by intermediate keyframes?

Comment: for example if you want to rotate a bone 180° but it works bad with only 2 keyframes, one at 0° and one at 180°, create some keyframes between the 2, like one at 30°, one at 90°, one at 120°

Comment: Thank you for explanation, but now I set it quaternion I just lost my animation data, the controller is not moving?

Comment: what bone are you talking about? Switching to quaternion can't remove the animation

Comment: But it removes the all keyframe

Comment: please show a animated gif because I don't see how it is possible

Comment: I have provided it on question

Comment: You're right, I'm going to edit my answer to put some new pictures

Comment: I think that I should start fresh again, what do you think

Comment: try to recreate some new keyframes like I show in my new edit, it seems to work fine

Comment: Ok, Thank you for spending your precious time on me.